# QLocalSocket: Socket access error (error 3)

Tags: qt, qt5, freebsd, qlocalsocket

Recently finished compiling qt5 and qutebrowser on my FreeBSD system. Qutebrowser runs well when I run as root but otherwise gives me this socket access error. Have never done anything with or used qt5 before. I am assuming this is a permissions issue and have found a stackoverflow question and responces on how to fix this in Windows. Have found out about setSocketOption but don't know how to execute this nor if this would fix my problem. Thanks!

Exact error given:

> Error while connecting to running instance:
>
> QLocalSocket::connectToServer: Socket access error (error 3)
>
> Maybe another instance is running but frozen?

Comment: What's the full path of the server instance you're trying to connect to (as returned by [`QLocalSocket::fullServerName()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalsocket.html#fullServerName))?  Does it refer to a part of the filesystem that a non-root account should have read/write access to?

Comment: It should be easy enough to provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the error, showing the paths etc. That would help answering a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From their [ICP class source](https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/blob/d34c6d495c1ec9843f5de658019b520987aed7a6/qutebrowser/misc/ipc.py), it seems to me like they are trying to initiate a local socket in the same folder as the `qutebrowser` executable

```
socketname = _get_socketname(args.basedir)
```

... where the `args` comes from the app itself, and the `socketname` is then used to create their IPC Server QLocalSocket. Which would mean that you need write permissions to its binary folder.

That being said, it looks a bit odd, so I would recommend filing an issue on their GitHub to have an answer from the maintainers!

https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser/issues

Hope that helps